# \newcommand and comma separated parameters

Tags: macros, comma-separated-list

I would like to learn to manipulate comma separated lists in Latex.
To give a concreet but artificial example, I would like to have this command:

```
\swap{1,10}
```

expand to this:

```
{10,1}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 9):

I think you should ask what you want in full generality. For your concrete example,

```
\newcommand*\swap[1]{\doswap#1\relax}
\def\doswap#1,#2\relax{{#2,#1}}
```

should work, although I didn't test it.

Comment: I didn't know how to ask before seeing the answer. Can you elaborate on what \relax does and why do I need separate \def ?

Comment: Normally, `\relax` tells TeX to do nothing. Here, I was just using it as a delimiter for the second argument to `\doswap`. As for why you need the separate `\def`, I cannot think of a way to do this without defining a second control sequence. `\swap` takes a single parameter and so I defined it so that `\swap{1,10}` expands to `\doswap 1,10\relax`. Then `\doswap` reads `1` as its first argument and `10` as its second argument and so it expands to `{10,1}`, exactly as you wanted.

Comment: This is really useful! How would one go about writing a `\newcommand` variant that does all this behind the scenes?

Comment: `\newcommand` doesn't allow you to define a macro with delimited arguments, so you cannot.