# Referring to delimiter separated arguments in new commands

Tags: macros, arguments

[Another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2858/28685) gave me hope that there is an elegant way (**without using additional packages**) to refer to a comma separated argument in `\newcommand`, maybe something like (just a guess, not tested):

```
\newcommand*\myfigure[3]{
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=#3]{#1}
    \caption[\getfirst#2]{\getsecond#2}
  \end{figure}
  \relax
}
\def\getfirst#1,#2\relax{{#1}}
\def\getsecond#1,#2\relax{{#2}}
```

that should allow to use a command such as:

```
\myfigure{imagefile}{short caption,long caption}{0.8\textwidth}
```

Unfortunately commas are often present in captions, so I would like to know if there is a way to obtain the desired result using another delimiter than comma.

Altough there are many similar question around, I did not find an elegant solution to my need.

**UPDATE**

Being a newbie, I discovered just now that I can use a custom delimiter in `\def` (any character rarely found in captions, such as `§`), so to avoid altogheter the comma issue. The *guessed* code does not work yet though, it seems that the second `\def` breaks it, with the error `Argument of \getsfirst has an extra }`. Does anybody know how to fix the code?

**FINAL UPDATE**

No wonder **egreg** knew how to fix the code (thanks!) which I report here (`§` chosen as delimiter), should it be useful to somebody (even if egreg's own answer, using another approach, should fit better most of similar needs):

```
\def\getfirst#1§#2\relax{#1}
\def\getsecond#1§#2\relax{#2}

\newcommand\myfigure[3]{
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=#3]{#1}
    \caption[\getfirst#2\relax]{\getsecond#2\relax}
    \label{fig:#1}
  \end{figure}
  \relax
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of `\myfigure` over a `figure` environment?

Comment: @egreg The advantage is conciseness, a single line instead of a multiline command. I use the same approach to build figures with multiple images horizontally or vertically aligned, with single or multiple captions, using just a single line.

Comment: It is possible but I would suggest a different syntax. The standard latex syntax for positional arguments is `{}` so it should be `{short caption}{long caption}` or use named (key-val) argument as in `\includegraphics` so `{shortc=short caption,longc=long caption}` That way the short caption can be made optional.  Also if you do define a command, don't forget `%` at the ends of lines!!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the delimiter of the second argument:

```
\newcommand*\myfigure[3]{
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=#3]{#1}
    \caption[\getfirst#2\relax]{\getsecond#2\relax}
  \end{figure}
}
\def\getfirst#1,#2\relax{{#1}}
\def\getsecond#1,#2\relax{{#2}}
```

However, I don't think you gain much with this syntax, over an explicit `figure` environment; for instance, you aren't providing for a `\label` to your figure.

I suggest a different syntax, using an optional argument for the short caption, which can be easily set up with `xparse`; the problem with separating the short caption from the long one with a comma is that frequently commas *are* in a caption, so you'd have to be very careful in bracing them and the advantage over two arguments would be lost.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfigure}{momm}{%
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=#4]{#1}
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\caption{#3}}{\caption[{#2}]{#3}}
  \end{figure}
}
```

You can call it as

```
\myfigure{imagefile}[short caption]{long caption}{0.8\textwidth}
```

when the short caption is necessary, or

```
\myfigure{imagefile}{long caption}{0.8\textwidth}
```

when there is no need for a short caption.

You may want to add an optional label:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfigure}{mommo}{%
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=#4]{#1}
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\caption{#3}}{\caption[{#2}]{#3}}
  \IfValueT{#5}{\label{#5}}
  \end{figure}
}
```

so the calls can be

```
\myfigure{imagefile}[short caption]{long caption}{0.8\textwidth}[label]

\myfigure{imagefile}{long caption}{0.8\textwidth}[label]
```

for providing also the (optional) label.

---

Without additional packages, you could do

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfigure}[1]{%
  \def\myfigure@file{#1}%
  \@dblarg\myfigure@caption
}
\def\myfigure@caption[#1]#2#3{%
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=#3]{\myfigure@file}
  \caption[{#1}]{#2}
  \end{figure}
}
\makeatother
```

With the optional trailing label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfigure}[1]{%
  \begin{figure}
  \def\myfigure@file{#1}%
  \@dblarg\myfigure@caption
}
\def\myfigure@caption[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\myfigure@short{#1}%
  \def\myfigure@long{#2}%
  \def\myfigure@width{#3}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\myfigure@withlabel}{\myfigure@end}%
}
\def\myfigure@withlabel[#1]{%
  \def\myfigure@label{#1}%
  \myfigure@end
}
\def\myfigure@end{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\myfigure@width]{\myfigure@file}
  \caption[\myfigure@short]{\myfigure@long}
  \ifx\myfigure@label\@empty\else\label{\myfigure@label}\fi
  \end{figure}
}
\let\myfigure@label\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\myfigure{example-image}[Short]{Long}{.8\textwidth}

\myfigure{example-image}{Long2}{.8\textwidth}[label]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not a direct solution to my question (I thought I could find a solution to my need in that way, my fault), but it actually suits perfectly my need, thanks! I'll test it right away.

Comment: @mmj I added the “classical” way to do it. One could add also the optional label, with some other trick.

Comment: By the way, from your answer I deduce that my orginal approach could work if I enclose non-delimiting commas in curly braces, isn't it? Can you take a look at my original guessed code? Looks like adding the last `\def` breaks the code(I get the error `Argument of \getsfirst has an extra }.`) , maybe I should move `\relax` somewhere else?

Comment: @mmj You're missing `\relax`: `\caption[\getfirst#2\relax]{\getsecond#2\relax}`

Comment: @mmj I edited my answer to add the information