# Pass a command as optional argument of environment

Tags: macros, environments, optional-arguments

Sorry for the beginner question, but I'd like to know if there is a robust way to do what the title says. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\myoptions}{h!tb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[\myoptions]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing something]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:whatever}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

gives the error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option '\'.`.

Actually I found a workaround (in my actual document the `\figure` environment is used by a new command that takes many parameters needed to define a figure and puts them inside `\figure`), but it gives problems with `\cite` command inside short caption, that's why I'm looking for a **robust** solution.

**SOLUTION**

Here is the solution to this question, that was given as a comment to the accepted answer:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\myoptions}{h!tb}

\def\tmp#1{\begin{figure}[#1]}% use tmp, in the form below, as many times as needed

\begin{document}

\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\myoptions}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing something]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:whatever}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are some technical issues why it doesn't work (it has never been supported syntax in latex2e) but you should never need to do this anyway. the optional argument (and especially `!`) are for one-off special cases where you need to fine-tune and over-ride the defaults. there should never be a need to _automate_ over-riding the default. If the default for a document type should be `htb` then define `fps@figure` to be `htb` and then no optional argument is needed to set that.

Comment: How do I set `fps@figure` to some value?

Comment: `\makeatletter` (or be inside a package file) then `\renewcommand\fps@figure{htp}`

Comment: Your "follow up" edit is impossible to understand.  The optional argument of figure has no effect on the optional argument of `\cite`. But if you want help with that do not edit the question to ask an unrelated question, ask a _new_ question and with a new the example demonstrate the error for which you want to get help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree, I deleted the follow up, and posted another question about the problem of citation in short caption: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269972/28685

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that you get an error in the texlive 2015 release but not earlier ones is due to it including fixes from the old `fixltx2e` package.

In earlier releases

```
\newcommand{\myoptions}{h!tb}
\begin{figure}[\myoptions]
```

Then `\myoptions` is not expanded and is just taken as the sequence of options
`\`,`m`,`y`,`o`,`p`,`t`,`i`,`o`,`n`,`s` unknown options were silently ignored so this is equivalent to `[pt]` not, as you might expect from the definition, to `[h!tb]`.

Had you done

```
\newcommand{\foo}{h!tb}
\begin{figure}[\foo]
```

then since *no* legal option is included (just`\`, `f` and two `o`), the figure is not allowed *anywhere* and so will always go to the end of the document or `\clearpage`.

The change in the `2015/01/01` release is that an error is raised for undefined float placement options so here you get an error on `\`.

Comment: Any clue on how to make `\myoptions` expand before `\begin{figure}` so that it can be used as an argument?

Comment: @mmj yes, although as I said in a comment on the question you should never need to do this. `\def\tmp#1{\begin{figure}[#1]}\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\myoptions}` would work though.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to an undocumented feature of the most recent release of LaTeX, since running the example with TeX Live 2014 doesn't raise the error. But no error doesn't mean it worked.

Building on the code I proposed for [Referring to delimiter separated arguments in new commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269444/referring-to-delimiter-separated-arguments-in-new-commands), here's a possibility, where the placement options are in leading position.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfigure}{O{!htbp}mommo}{%
  \begin{figure}[#1]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=#5]{#2}
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\caption{#4}}{\caption[{#3}]{#4}}
  \IfValueT{#6}{\label{#6}}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Test}

Text

\myfigure{example-image-a}[Short]{Long}{.4\textwidth}

\myfigure{example-image-b}{Long2}{.4\textwidth}[label1]

Text

\myfigure[p]{example-image-c}{Long2}{.8\textwidth}[label2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to answer the “abstract” question, a robust way for passing the macro as the optional argument is to reset `\fps@figure`:

```
\begingroup\makeatletter\let\fps@figure\myoptions\makeatother
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
\endgroup
```

Of course, this would be hidden in some macro:

```
\newcommand\myoptions{!htbp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfigure}[<n>]{%
  \begingroup\let\fps@figure\myoptions
  \begin{figure}
  ...
  \end{figure}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

In case you want to have `!htbp` as default placement specifier for *all* figure environments, just issue

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\fps@figure}{!htbp}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Glad to know that this behaviour is due to a bug. Unfortunately the solution you propose still has the problem that `\cite` commands in short caption are ignored (while argument of `\cite` is displayed in  list of figures as text). The strange is that if in the new command you use `\begin{figure}` instead of `\begin{figure}[#1]`, citing in short caption works.

Comment: @mmy actually this isn't a bug (or really a change in behaviour).

Comment: @mmj I added `\cite` in both the short and the long captions and I have no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @egreg I tracked down the specific problem of citation in short caption, I posted another question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269972/28685