# Citations not found in short captions

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, captions

I'm experimenting problems with citations in short captions. If I run the following MWE, three citations are found as expected, but if I add some text (any text) in the document by enabling the commented `\lipsum`, no citation is found, the bibliography is empty and the argument of `\fullcite` is displayed in the list of figures as text.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{cosimo, author = "D'Angela, Cosimo", title = "La Cripta della Cattedrale di Taranto", publisher = "Scorpione editrice", year = 1986}
@book{farella, author = "Farella, Vittorio", title = "La citta' vecchia di Taranto", publisher = "Samarcanda edizioni", year = 1988}
@book{polibio, author = "Polibio", title = "Storie", volume = "Libro III", publisher = "Edizioni Rizzoli", year = 1961}
@book{porsia, author = "Porsia, Franco and Scionti, Mauro", title = "Le citta' nella storia d'Italia: Taranto", publisher = "Laterza edizioni", year = 1989}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

%\lipsum
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing \fullcite{porsia}]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing \fullcite{farella}]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing \fullcite{cosimo}]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\backmatter
\listoffigures
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Puzzling, indeed!

Comment: If you are interested to create an even more weird phenomenon, try writing only the word `lorem` where you now have the `\lipsum` command. In my tests the first two citations worked, but the third failed. This was because the citations to the first two items were written into the `.aux` file before switching `citerequest` to false in LoFs, while the third is written after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does look a bit mysterious indeed. And it makes me think that the `citerequest` boolean does a bit more than advertised.
According to §4.11.5 *Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF*, p. 239, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

> If a citation is given in a float (typically in the caption of a
>   figure or table), scholarly back references like ‘ibidem’ or back
>   references based on the page tracker get ambiguous because floats
>   are objects which are (physically and logically) placed outside the
>   flow of text, hence the logic of such references applies poorly to
>   them. To avoid any such ambiguities, the citation and page trackers
>   are temporarily disabled in all floats. In addition to that, these
>   trackers plus the back reference tracker (`backref`) are temporarily
>   disabled in the table of contents, the list of figures, and the list
>   of tables.

In reality, this boolean seems to be able to disable entire cite commands because it influences the definition of `\blx@citation`.

Toggling `citerequest` back to true in the toc/lof seems to resolve our problem.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
     \booltrue{citerequest}%
     \boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \boolfalse{backtracker}\relax}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
     \booltrue{citerequest}%
     \boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \boolfalse{backtracker}\relax}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{%
     \booltrue{citerequest}%
     \boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \boolfalse{backtracker}\relax}%
  \patchcmd\addtocontents
    {\string\@writefile}
    {\string\@writefile{##1}{\defcounter{refsection}{\the\c@refsection}\relax}%
     \string\@writefile}
    {}
    {\blx@err@patch{\string\addtocontents}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{cosimo, author = "D'Angela, Cosimo", title = "La Cripta della Cattedrale di Taranto", publisher = "Scorpione editrice", year = 1986}
@book{farella, author = "Farella, Vittorio", title = "La citta' vecchia di Taranto", publisher = "Samarcanda edizioni", year = 1988}
@book{polibio, author = "Polibio", title = "Storie", volume = "Libro III", publisher = "Edizioni Rizzoli", year = 1961}
@book{porsia, author = "Porsia, Franco and Scionti, Mauro", title = "Le citta' nella storia d'Italia: Taranto", publisher = "Laterza edizioni", year = 1989}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\lipsum
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing \fullcite{porsia}]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing \fullcite{farella}]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{whatever}
  \caption[Short caption citing \fullcite{cosimo}]{Long caption.}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\backmatter
\listoffigures
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

A shorter, potentially - but not actually - more dangerous solution would be to just have

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@citation#1#2{\blx@citation@entry{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

That is, removing the if construct involving `citerequest`.

Comment: I applied your first patch to the complex document I was compiling and it worked, thanks.