# Misplaced \noalign when trying to define a command for cmidrules

Tags: tables, counters, rules, pgfkeys, arguments

When trying to maintain large tables with `\cmidrule`s, I find them tedious to use, so I thought I'd define my own shortcut. Instead of writing `\cmidrule{1-3} \cmidrule{4-5}` I would simply write `\cmidrulez{3,2}` (because the first rule is 3 columns wide and the second one 2.

In order to support an arbitrary amount of comma-seperated arguments, I tried to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303960/72038):

```
\newcounter{mainargs}
\pgfkeys{mainargs/.is family, mainargs,
step counter/.code=\stepcounter{mainargs},
add argument/.style={step counter, arg\themainargs/.initial={#1}},
}

\newcounter{optargs}
\newif\ifoptargs
\pgfkeys{optargs/.is family, optargs,
    opt args present/.is if=optargs,
    step counter/.code=\stepcounter{optargs},
    add argument/.style={opt args present=true, step counter, arg\theoptargs/.initial={#1}},
}

\newcommand{\cmidrulez}[2][]{%
    \setcounter{mainargs}{0}%
    \pgfkeys{mainargs, add argument/.list={#2}}%
    \setcounter{optargs}{0}%
    \pgfkeys{optargs, add argument/.list={#1}}%
    %
    \newcounter{cmrstart}%
    \newcounter{cmrend}%
    \setcounter{cmrstart}{1}%
    \ifoptargs%
        \foreach \n in {1,...,\theoptargs}{%
            \setcounter{cmrstart}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/optargs/arg\n}}%
        }%
    \fi%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,\themainargs}{%
    \setcounter{cmrend}{\value{cmrstart}}%
   \addtocounter{cmrend}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/mainargs/arg\n}}%
    \addtocounter{cmrend}{-1}%
    \cmidrule{\arabic{cmrstart}-\arabic{cmrend}}%
    \setcounter{cmrstart}{\value{cmrend}}%
    \stepcounter{cmrstart}%
    }%
    %
}
```

Essentially what I'm doing is using two counters to calculate the corresponding numbers I need to give to the `\cmidrule` command. When I print the numbers with `\arabic{cmrstart}` and `\arabic{cmrend}` instead of calling `\cmidrule` the correct values appear, so this part is working.

However, when I try to use this in a table (where a `\cmidrule` would work) it complains about a "misplaced \noalign":

```
\cmidrule ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@cmidrule }{\@cmidrule ...
l.66         \cmidrulez{2,1}
                             \\
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.66         \cmidrulez{2,1}
                             \\
```

I first thought this might have something to do with how I hand over the values, so I tried `\value{cmrstart}` and `thecmrstart`, the other two ways of which I know to get a value from a counter, but that didn't work. In fact, if I just replace the arguments of `\cmidrule` with hardcoded integers (inside my command definition), the problem persists, so it can't (only) be that.

When I define a much simpler command that just does something like `\cmidrule{1-3}` it works without problems, but as soon as there are arguments it fails:

```
% this works:
\newcommand{\cmidrules}{%
    \cmidrule{1-3}%
}
% this doesn't:
\newcommand{\cmidrules}[1][]{%
    \cmidrule{1-3}%
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're writing a macro to replace a hyphen with a comma??

Comment: It cannot work: `\cmidrule` should not be preceded by anything else than other `\cmidrule` commands. With your `\cmidrulez` command you're adding something that makes TeX start a row of the `tabular`.

Comment: @Bernard No, I want to replace several `\cmidrule` invokations with a single auto-incrementing call to my command.

Comment: the macro has to be expandable so you can not do assignments or allocate counters, but even for normal cases  you should not do `\newcounter{cmrstart}%` inside the macro just allocate the counter once in the package or document preamble. You do not want to allocate a new counter every time the macro is used. They are a finite resource.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good to know, thank you. It's the first time I've used anything like this. And thank you for the "expandable" explanation, that was what was missing from my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do assignments before issuing `\cmidrule`, unless they're inside `\noalign`.

Here's my version, where I also add `*` to leave a column empty. I also added `(lr)` for `\cmidrule`, otherwise `\cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{4-5}` would be exactly the same as `\cmidrule{1-5}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\cmidrulez}{m}
 {
  \noalign { \__leviathan_cmidrulez:n { #1 } }
  \tl_use:N \g__leviathan_cmidrulez_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \g__leviathan_cmidrulez_tl
\int_new:N \l__leviathan_cmidrulez_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__leviathan_cmidrulez:n
 {
  \tl_gclear:N \g__leviathan_cmidrulez_tl
  \int_zero:N \l__leviathan_cmidrulez_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { * }
     {% no rule here
      \int_incr:N \l__leviathan_cmidrulez_int
     }
     {
      \tl_gput_right:Nx \g__leviathan_cmidrulez_tl
       {
        \exp_not:N \cmidrule(lr)
         {% start
          \int_eval:n { \l__leviathan_cmidrulez_int + 1 }
          -
          \int_eval:n { \l__leviathan_cmidrulez_int + ##1 }
         }
       }
      \int_add:Nn \l__leviathan_cmidrulez_int { ##1 }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\cmidrulez{3,2}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\cmidrulez{*,3,*,2}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The comma separated list is scanned and if the item is `*` the internal counter is just stepped. Otherwise the proper argument for `\cmidrule` is prepared by using the current value of the counter (plus 1) and the required number of steps. Then the counter is updated. The command is appended to a token list variable that's issued after `\noalign` has ended.

I'm not sure how much this can be useful, though. How many `\cmidrule` commands do you have in your document?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works!

Comment: And sadly, there's often quite a few cmidrules; this is most useful when I'm changing the structure of a table all the time (e.g. inserting a column near the beginning etc.).

Answer (score 3):

A solution with an 'expandable' programmation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \clinez } { m } { \__leviathan:nn { 1 } { #1 , } }
\cs_new:Nn \__leviathan:nn 
  { \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { \__leviathan:nnn #2 \q_stop { #1 } } }
\cs_new:Npn \__leviathan:nnn #1 , #2 \q_stop #3
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { * }
      { \__leviathan:nn { \int_eval:n { #3 + 1 } } { #2 } }
      {
        \__leviathan:nn { \int_eval:n { #1 + #3 } } { #2 }
        \cmidrule (lr) { #3 - \int_eval:n { #3 + #1 - 1 } } 
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\
\clinez{3,2,2}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\
\clinez{3,*,2,2}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: How would I use this to do the equivalent of `\cmidrule{1-3} \cmidrule{3-4}`?

Comment: You are right. There was a little problem and I have modified my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to skip columns with this implementation (like it is by using `*` in the other answer)?

Comment: I will add that.

Comment: I have modified my answer to add the required feature.

Answer (score 3):

Macros in that position need to be expandable to avoid starting the next table cell.

It may be easier to see the expansion working directly rather than using package code in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\def\cmidrulez#1{\cmz{}1#1,{-1},}
\def\gobblethree#1#2#3{}
\def\cmz#1#2#3,{%
\ifnum#3=-1 
#1\expandafter\gobblethree\fi
\cmz{#1\cmidrule(lr){#2-\the\numexpr#2+#3-1\relax}}{\the\numexpr#2+#3\relax}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
 1&2&3&4&5\\
\cmidrulez{3,2}
 1&2&3&4&5\\
 1&2&3&4&5\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```